# How do I select data from a specific time during the day only in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing some .csv data using python on Jupyter Notebook for analysis. I have set the start_time and the end_time to be the same for both data frames and it's over a period of a few months with a half-hourly interval.

However, I am only interested in using data from 9 am-5 pm each day and would like to separate them for analysis. How do I do that?

The existing code:

```
__version__ = '0.3'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import_price1 = pd.read_csv('data/octopus_imprt_price_southern.csv', index_col=0,parse_dates=["local_time"])
export_price1 = pd.read_csv('data/octopus_export_price_southern.csv', index_col=0,parse_dates=["local_time"])

start_time = "2019-1-31 00:00:00"
end_time = "2019-5-15 22:30:00"

import_price2 =import_price1.loc[start_time:end_time]
export_price2 =export_price1.loc[start_time:end_time]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
import_price1 = import_price1.between_time('09:00:00','17:00:00')
```